# Deserialize java.time.ZoneId using Jackson in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, java-time

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
private LocalDateTime accessStart;

private ZoneId accessStartZoneId;
```

Is there a built-in pattern mapper in Jackson to map JSON request containing a java `ZoneId`?

```
{
  "accessStart": "2017-10-10T10:10:10.100",
  "accessStartZoneID": "Australia/Sydney"
}
```

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE. How to configure the deserializer for `ZoneId`? It works well with `accessStart`

> JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of java.time.ZoneId: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

Comment: A `ZoneId` is serialized to its ID (such as `Europe/London`). Are you expecting a different format? How is your JSON requests that contain `ZoneId`? And is there any reason to use a `LocalDateTime` and `ZoneId` separately instead of just using a `ZonedDateTime`?

Comment: @Hugo see updates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### A step back

I'm particularly curious to know why you are using [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) along with [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html). Wouldn't it be easier to use *only* [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)?

In terms of design, [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) is a combination of a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) and a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).

### Supporting `ZoneId`

Assuming that you still want to use [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html), you can write your own custom (de)serializer.

Alternatively, you can add the [`jackson-datatype-jsr310`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310) artifact to your dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

And then register the [`JavaTimeModule`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-jsr310/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) module in your `ObjectMapper`:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

In a Spring Boot application, you need the following:

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {  
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

[`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) is supported according to the [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime):

> - `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset`, which do not actually store dates and times but are supported with this module nonetheless.

Comment: thanks for this, I forgot to mention that im using spring boot

Comment: @LemuelNabong The solution with `jackson-datatype-jsr310` is still valid for Spring Boot.